# Combining static blog & react web-app on single domain? (gatsbyjs / reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hosting, gatsby

Imagine the following scenario:

1. I have a static website / blog, built with gatsbyjs.
2. I also have a react webapp, which is not static, and to which users can sign into and do some other stuff.

I would like the user to be able to go to e.g. `wwww.mywebapp.com` and then either log into my non-static react web-app, OR click on `blog` and read my (static) gatsbyjs blog.

Is there a way for me to do this / combine the two? Or might I be better off using serverside rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build dynamic apps inside Gatsby. The approach is described in the [docs here](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/). But the general approach is:

- Use Gatsby as normal
- Add some client only routes

The client only routes will not be server rendered. More info in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that by modifying public(build) folder , package.json and gatsby.config....

Tutorial :- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rUNlYs6wu4

Code :- https://github.com/benawad/gatsby-cra-combo

Hope this will also help !!!